# Ruby shotgun debugging configuration in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, rubymine, shotgun

How would you set up a shotgun debugging configuration in Intellij or RubyMine?

Answer (score 3):

On RubyMine you have to set up shotgun as a `Run/Debug Configuration`.

The configuration is easy because shotgun comes as a gem. See my configuration:

[image]

After you did that, you can select shotgun from the `Select Run/Debug Configuration` in the menu bar. Hit the bug instead of the run icon and the debugger will start using shotgun.

[image]

Comment: This worked for me after I had to ticked 'Run the script in context of the bundler (bundle exec)' on the Bundler page

Comment: This worked for me too (years later)! This ought to be the accepted answer.